# Google Map API: Find out different points between 2 locations at a distance of say 1km

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

This might be the old question, but somehow I couldn't find the answer anywhere. Let's assume there are 2 locations, A & B, and using Google Maps API, we can find the distance, time and direction between them.

My use case is little different. I want different points (with respective latitude and longitude) on the route between these locations after every say 1km. How can I find those points?

I tried most of the APIs provided by Google maps, but couldn't find such points. When I use Direction API, then in response I can see "polyline" with some "points". Can I use it in this use case? How to read this Polyline point string if I am on the correct path?

```
"polyline": {

      "points": "some encoded string"
}
```

Else let me know if you will be aware of any better alternate solution.

Comment: What do you want exactly? To have not just two points but a set of points on the line, connecting A and B?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I want set of points on the line(road), connecting A & B

Comment: Is it strictly a straight line or a road path?

Comment: It is a road path and not the actual aerial straight line between 2 locations.

Comment: Do you have a `Polyline` object? Create a simple script that iterates through vertices.

Comment: How to do that? When called direction API, that time I got polyline response  as mentioned in my question. But that is a kind of some longgg string

Comment: You get polyline coords as a json string, `var dat = JSON.parse(str)` and use it.

Comment: Ahh, you're talking about encoding. Well, decode first.

Comment: And how to decode it? And after decode, is it enough to find multiple points from it?

Comment: Based on the tags in the question `javascript` and `google-maps-api-3` can we assume that you would like to implement this using Google Maps JavaScript API?

Comment: Use `decodePath` and some programming to split path into 1km fragments.